# TODO delete function not working

Tags: javascript, html

I’m unable to delete a newly added item in my todo list. Below is my JavaScript code.

```
var deletes = document.querySelectorAll('.delete')

deletes.forEach(function(removeTodo) {
  ul = document.querySelector('ul');
  removeTodo.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log(removeTodo.parentNode.parentNode);

    const li = removeTodo.parentNode;

    ul.removeChild(li);
  });
});
```

Comment: please show your html dom

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors. What’s the point of `ul = document.querySelector('ul');` inside the `forEach`?

Comment: Maybe you have a few ul's in DOM, so the first ul you get is not the parent of the li you want to remove. Anyway, you don't really need the ul. you can do li.remove().

Comment: Hi below is my HTML.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Shopping List</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="TODO_App_css.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div id="enter div" class="inputdiv">
  <h1>Add Items to the List</h1>
  <input type="text" id="inputtext" class="inputtext" placeholder="Enter Item to List">
  <button class="button" id="add">Add</button>
 </div> 

 <ul id="myUL">
  <!--  <li>Hit the gym <button class="delete">Delete</button></li> -->
  </ul>

<script type="text/javascript" src="TODO_App_js.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope my code will help you. If you have some questions please ask me – write a comment.

```js
var deletes = document.querySelectorAll('.delete'),
    dones = document.querySelectorAll('.done');
    
//convert NodeList to array for IE
deletes = [].slice.call(deletes, 0);
dones = [].slice.call(dones, 0);

deletes.forEach(function(removeTodo)
{
    removeTodo.addEventListener('click', function()
    {
        var li = removeTodo.parentNode;
        li.parentNode.removeChild(li);
    });
});

dones.forEach(function(doneTodo)
{
    doneTodo.addEventListener('click', function()
    {
        var elStyle = this.previousElementSibling.style,
            value = elStyle.textDecoration;

        elStyle.textDecoration = value == 'line-through' ? 'none' : 'line-through';
        this.title = value != 'line-through' ? 'to do' : 'done';
    });
});
```

```css
li{margin:5px 0}
li span
{
    display:inline-block;
    white-space:nowrap;
    width:170px;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    vertical-align:middle
}
.delete
{
    border:2px solid #f99;
    color:#f99;
    background-color:#fdd;
}
.done
{
    border:2px solid #6f6;
    color:#6f6;
    background-color:#dfd;
}
.done,.delete
{
    border-radius:50%;
    display:inline-block;
    line-height:12px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><span>Child 1 – "Buy fruits"</span> <b class="done" title="done">&#x2714;</b> <b class="delete" title="delete">&#10799;</b></li>
    <li><span>Child 2 – "Meet parents"</span> <b class="done" title="done">&#x2714;</b> <b class="delete" title="delete">&#10799;</b></li>
    <li><span>Child 3 – "Read a book"</span> <b class="done" title="done">&#x2714;</b> <b class="delete" title="delete">&#10799;</b></li>
    <li><span>Child 4 – "Organize office"</span> <b class="done" title="done">&#x2714;</b> <b class="delete" title="delete">&#10799;</b></li>
    <li><span>Child 5 – "Hit the gym"</span> <b class="done" title="done">&#x2714;</b> <b class="delete" title="delete">&#10799;</b></li>
    <li><span>Child 6 – "Pay bills"</span> <b class="done" title="done">&#x2714;</b> <b class="delete" title="delete">&#10799;</b></li>
</ul>
```